# Angular 8 Background Images url from Assets/img/img1.jpg folder is not working

Tags: html, angular

I am working on angular 8 and trying to bind an image in "Assets -> img -> img1.jpg" to my controller css. how can i do it.

```
.slider {
  background-image: url(/assets/img/landing.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

** i have tried to add "assets" folder in angular.json.
** i have tried to move assets/img folder in app folder and then try. 
** i have even tried to put the image in the same controller folder and then try to give reference of image in URL. this is not working for me Image is not shown on screen.

folder structure
 SRC |-> apps    |->   controller  |->  homeController |-> home.component.css
     |-> assets  |->   img         |->  img1.jpg

Comment: Can you add an image of your folder structure with your question?

Comment: Check your console, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

that might help:

```
.slider {
background-image: url(~src/assets/img/landing.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: i tried doing that but it did not helped.. i believe i might use IMG rather than background css prop for div.